# Approximation of characteristic function of compact sets via $C_0$ functions

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

In Kallenberg Proposition 19.14 this purely topological statement seems to be used and I don't understand it.

Let $\Omega$ be a completely regular locally compact space. Denote by $\hat{\Omega}$ the one-point compactification by the element ${*}$. Assume that we are given a Radon probability measure $\mu$ on $\hat{\Omega}$ with the property that
$$
\int_\mu \hat{u} dx=0
$$
for all $u\in C_0(\Omega)$ extended by $\hat{u}(*)=0$.

**Show:** All the mass lies with $*$, i.e. $\mu(*)=1$.

**My approach:** Let $K\subseteq\Omega$ be an arbitrary compact set. By "some" approximation theorem, be it Tietzsche or Urysohn, we find a $C_0(\Omega)$ function $u$ with $\chi_K\leq u$. Hence $\mu(K)=0$, but since the measure $\mu$ is Radon, we know that
$$
\mu(\Omega)=\sup_{K\subseteq\Omega \text{ compact}}\mu(K)=0.
$$
We conclude $\mu(*)=1-\mu(\Omega)=1$.

**Question:** Can somebody provide me the "some" approximation theorem with precise conclusions to this particular case? I somehow fail to find the correct argumentation here. Perhaps because the statement is false?

Comment: I think all is OK. The "some" statement is the Urysohn Lemma. It gives you that function $u$, which is $1$ on $K$ and vanishes outside of an open neighborhood of $K$ with compact closure, that is to say, $u(\ast)=0$. (I like how this lemma is treated on Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" (search for a section called "Topological preliminaries", it is there)).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you most kindly. Indeed I have laying around here (even multiple copies :-) a version of Rudin's Real and Complex anlaysis. It seems I wasn't researching properly. Combining Theorem 2.7 and 2.12 Urysohns lemma yields the result for my case.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the correct statement is the lemma of Urysohn, as in Rudin's "Real and complex analysis", §2.7, §2.12.